# Вопрос по регулярным выражениям

Tags: php

Как мне из "https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing?name=mvc" получить просто routing?

Comment: и как получить тоже самое если нет get

Comment: `и как получить тоже самое если нет get` - что это значит?

Comment: если без ?name=mvc будет эта ссылка https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing?name=mvc

Comment: нифига не ясно. нужно взять конкретное слово чтоли?

Comment: Да последнее самое перед ?name=mvc к примеру если этого нет то брать просто последнее слово в ссылке

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLastFromUrl($url) {
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    $last = '';

    if (isset($parsed['query'])) {
        $last = $parsed['query'];
    } else {
        $pathParts = explode('/', $parsed['path']);
        $last = end($pathParts);        
    }

    return $last;
}


echo getLastFromUrl('https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing?googleguy=googley&test=yo'); // googleguy=googley&test=yo
echo getLastFromUrl('https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing'); // routing
```

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) - Разбирает URL и возвращает его компоненты

Далее анализируется `query` - если он есть - значит был гет запрос, если нет, значит берется последний элемент